# ZMQ poll and send at the same time from different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, zeromq

I have a program that uses ZMQ to send and receive between a C++ application and a Python GUI. The Python sends all commands to the C++ app to do the work, the C++ app periodically sends back status to update the GUI.

The C++ is multi-theaded but we never made the call `zmq_send` thread safe, so in 1 out of 100,000 runs we'd get an unhandled exception or segmentation fault if two threads tried to send status back to the gui simultaneously. This took longer than I care to admit figuring out since it was so sporadic. This was easily solved with a mutex around `zmq_send` because the socket is managed by a singleton.

In addition to the processing threads, there is one thread that just idly waits to receive and dispatch commands from the gui using `zmq_poll` and then `zmq_msg_recv` when something is available.

The question, can I safely poll the same socket while a send is happening? Most of the time the receive thread is sitting in `zmq_poll` with a timeout, and sends seem to be happening without issue. I can't seem to find any good documentation about this. I assume a mutex needs to protect `zmq_send` and `zmq_msg_recv` from occurring simultaneously, but I am not sure about the safety of polling while sending.

Details about the setup: using PAIR interface with a single client and server. All messages are small (<1KB). There is only one socket shared for sending and receiving.

This is a large, decade old application I'd like to avoid redesigning if possible.

Answer (score 0):

All I have ever seen in the zeromq documentation is sockets should never be shared between threads.  I understand your issue though, redesigning a large old application is never fun.

Is it possible you could just switch out the socket to use one of the newer thread safe ones?  I know you are using `PAIR` but maybe one of the following would give you the same functionality

Thread safe patterns:

- ZMQ_CLIENT
- ZMQ_SERVER
- ZMQ_DISH
- ZMQ_RADIO
- ZMQ_SCATTER
- ZMQ_GATHER

Comment: To add a bit of complication to this, we use ZMQ accepting commands from the GUI and sending status back to the GUI as stated above. We chose this (years ago) to allow others to make a replacement for our GUI, and ZMQ_PAIR is what the others are expected to use, so I imagine it is going to be an extra challenge attempting to change it and I doubt ZMQ_PAIR could be used on one side but not the other. I do think any of those would be a better choice if we were starting this project today instead of 10 years ago